# How to get CoordinatesToolOption working for List and DateListPlots

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get the Getcoordinate tool tip on `ListPlot` and `DateListPlots` displaying for example the date instead of the `AbsoluteTime`. While the `CoordinatesToolOption` works for `Plot` (at least in 10.4.1 OSX) it seems not to work for `ListPlot` and `DateListPlot`.
How can I get this to work for those plot functions?

```
plotCopiedValueF[x_] := (SetPrecision[#, 10] & /@ x);
plotDisplayF[{x_, y_}] := (InputForm /@ {N[x/10], y});

Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"CopiedValueFunction" -> plotCopiedValueF,
    "DisplayFunction" -> plotDisplayF}]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]], 
CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"CopiedValueFunction" -> plotCopiedValueF,
    "DisplayFunction" -> plotDisplayF}]
```

[image]

BTW none of this is working at all in MMA 11.0.1 on OSX.